# iOS Frameworks, embed another framework or library?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, xcode6

So in Xcode 6, we finally have the possibility to create and distribute our own libraries as Frameworks (as opposed to Static Libraries before).

The question, is it possible to "embed" another framework or library directly inside the framework rather than ask the end user to link them?

The reason is as follow: Creating and distributing frameworks for other people often requires them to manually add whichever framework we link against.
That's fine when these libraries are a default ones that can be added straight from Xcode, but when we need to link against other public frameworks.
One example would be if the framework uses AWS as a backend, it's a bit overkill to ask developers to also download a specific version of their SDK and link against specific bits that are required. And it becomes more overkill when we need others for performance logging or more.

On OSX, there is the possibility to use Umbrella Frameworks, but it's undocumented on iOS.

Thank you.

Comment: Cocoapods is a solution for linking against other frameworks. Don't know if it applies, but I would recommend strongly.

Comment: Thanks. It's true that when distributing on Cocoapods, it's not a problem.  It is however when distributing as a downloadable stand-alone framework.

Answer (score 5):

Recently done this myself on iOS, unfortunately any framework that has sub-frameworks must also be linked to in the project the parent framework gets used in.

Create the framework as per normal, and include the other frameworks under that framework (it should be an aggregate target).

Then build the parent framework, and link this into the main project. Attempt to compile and it will mention that it needs it sub-frameworks also linked. You can then link these sub-frameworks in addition and it will compile.

This is unfortunately a limitation of Xcode/iOS as it currently stands.

Comment: Thank you. I've done this for a static library and its Bundle (images, controllers, etc). Which is fine when the number is small.  
The problem is when using another framework (in this case, AWS), there is also the possibility that the target App already has AWS support, and the fact that the number is too high that our framework will become hard to implement. I wonder if there is a better solution?

Comment: You could use Cocoapods or Carthage to manage the dependencies a little easier, then end-users of your framework just have to specify all the framework names and versions instead of manually adding each one.

Comment: I like this solution. That way any project that wants to use a framework that wraps my framework the project will have to include my framework too :)

Comment: Does this still hold true in 2020? I am getting tons of “Class … is implemented in both … . One of the two will be used” prints in the console